# Calculating XPath of XML Document based on knowledge of name of tag and its value

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<bookstore>
    <book>
        <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
        <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
        <account_number>1111 1111 1111 1111</account_number>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>30.00</price>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
        <author>J K. Rowling</author>
        <account_number>2222 2222 2222 2222</account_number>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>29.99</price>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
        <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
        <account_number>3333 3333 3333 3333</account_number>
        <year>2003</year>
        <price>39.95</price>
    </book>
</bookstore>
```

I am interested in finding the XPath of **account_number** having value **2222 2222 2222 2222**.
Please guide me as to how I can get the XPath knowing the tag and its value.

Answer (score 3):

```
//account_number[text()='neededValue']
```

This means all `account_number` elements with `[neededValue]`.

If you would like the book parent element for this:

```
//account_number[text()='neededValue']/ancestor::book/
```

Then:

```
//account_number[text()='neededValue']/ancestor::book/OPTION
```

Where `OPTION` can be `title`, `author`, `year`, `price` etc. in order to get the other elements from that book with the specific account number.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt replies. One more challenge here is if I dont have the XML File with me but just knowledge of some tag and its value, in that case how to find XPath of that tag?? Some reverse engineering is required to trace from the tag to its root.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the context node `.` in your `[a=b]` predicate, it will be converted to a string before comparison to the right part "2222 2222 2222 2222"

```
//account_number[.="2222 2222 2222 2222"]
```

If you want a parent node based on its children value, you can nest your XPath within another predicate. For example if you want all books with a specific account number you can use:

```
//book[account_number[.="2222 2222 2222 2222"]]

------                |-- child value test--|
   ^
   |   |----   matching child condition  -----|
   |
   +--- all book descendants from the root node
```

To get the titles of these books, you continue the preceding XPath with `title`

```
//book[account_number[.="2222 2222 2222 2222"]]/title
```

---

Edit: coming back to this answer, there's an even simpler version

```
//book[account_number="2222 2222 2222 2222"]/title
```

The `account_number` node is converted to it's string content before comparing with `"2222 2222 2222 2222"`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt replies. One more challenge here is if I dont have the XML File with me but just knowledge of some tag and its value, in that case how to find XPath of that tag?? Some reverse engineering is required to trace from the tag to its root.